# React Hooks / Unnecessary component rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with unnecessary rendering
basically i have a hook for a theme switch, but every time i type something in my text area i end up rendering my theme unnecessarily:

[image]

basically almost all of my components will use my theme so i think maybe this is something problematic

my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const handleClick = () => {
    setText('');
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <button
          css={css`
            background: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 10px;
          `}
          onClick={() =>
            theme.setTheme(
              theme.type === 'dark' ? { type: 'light' } : { type: 'dark' },
            )
          }
        >
          a
        </button>
        <textarea
          onKeyPress={e => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              handleClick();
            }
          }}
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem"
        />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

my hook:

```
export default function useTheme(defaultTheme = lightTheme) {
  const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  function getInitialTheme() {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (savedTheme === 'dark' || savedTheme === 'light') {
      return JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
    } else {
      return defaultTheme;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme.type));
  }, [theme]);

  return {
    ...theme,
    setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme(darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme(lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

and my component that uses the theme:

```
const Top = props => {
  console.log(props.theme);
  return (
    <HeaderTop>
      <div></div>
    </HeaderTop>
  );
};

const Header = () => {
  const Theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Container theme={Theme}>
      <Content theme={Theme} flexdirection={'column'}>
        <Top theme={Theme} />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you make a sandbox? (codesandbox.io)

Comment: What do you log in the console ? It's normal that `useTheme` is executed every time as you update the state of `App`, it will call `useTheme` on every update. This does not mean that your theme is changing

Comment: I gave a console.log on my theme in my main app
and in my component that use my useTheme where I get the theme for props

Comment: @DennisVash https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-leaf-nf5yk here bro

Comment: You are rendering the ThemeProvider inside a component where the component state changes, so of course it rerenders. The App component and all its children will rerender every time `text` state changes.

Comment: ta solution would be to move the theme provider to index.js
but in relation to other components could you help me how do i solve this?

basically if i put the textarea in a component q i use my theme it will change even without having changed

Comment: @DennisVash can help me bro?

Comment: Your `App` component is the top level component of your app. It is a place where you should render things like `ThemeProvider` and other provider components. It is not a place where you store local state that changes frequently, so why are you storing `text` state in your `App` component? Also why do you declare `const theme = useTheme();` in your `App` component when the `ThemeProvider` is rendered **inside** the `App` component?

Comment: i'm a little confused by this i had found this solution i don't know if it's a good option, could you help me how can i solve this?

I thought I did it right, but now I'm confused

Comment: Regarding the state of the text, I only did it to text if it would render my theme and I already understood about it, but if I put my text in my header component and in my header component I get my theme as a prop it keeps rendering, and in relation to useTheme where would it be better to use?

Comment: What do you mean it keeps rendering? Which component keeps rendering? Your `useTheme` hook? That's because you're calling the hook inside a component (`App`) that is re-rendering. I have posted an answer below, please have a read and comment if you have questions.

Comment: I did the following to test
I moved my state text to my component header (where I use emotion's useTheme)
and I pass my theme as props for my component, but for some reason and it continued rendering when I type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the [codesandbox for you here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-chebyshev-7pqnn).

There were a few issues with your code:

---

## Passing a theme to ThemeProvider

In your `useTheme` hook you were spreading the `theme` object and returning it:

```
// useTheme.js
return {
  ...theme,
  setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
    if (theme.type === "dark") {
      return _setTheme(darkTheme);
    } else {
      return _setTheme(lightTheme);
    }
  }
}

// App.js
const theme = useTheme();
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

`ThemeProvider` expects a simple object, so you should just pass the `theme` straight out of your `useTheme` hook without spreading it, and pass that to the provider:

```
// useTheme.js
return {
  theme, // don't spread
  setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
    if (theme.type === "dark") {
      return _setTheme(darkTheme);
    } else {
      return _setTheme(lightTheme);
    }
  }
}

// App.js
const { theme } = useTheme();
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

I also renamed your `useTheme` hook to `useAppTheme` because it will get confused with Emotion's `useTheme` hook which you use in every other component.

---

## Setting state in your App component

The `App` component is the top level of your app, so if it re-renders, the whole app re-renders. You want to avoid this, because the whole point of using React is to NOT have to re-render the whole app every time something changes.

I removed any state from your `App` component, and it now looks like this:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { jsx } from "@emotion/core";
import { ThemeProvider } from "emotion-theming";
import GlobalStyle from "./globalStyle";
import Page from "./page";
import useAppTheme from "./useAppTheme";

export default function App() {
  const { theme } = useAppTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rendering app");
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Page />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

I've left the `useEffect` in there to log when the `App` renders - which you will see only happens once on initialization.

I moved all your logic to the new component `Page`, which is the component that will re-render when state changes:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/core";
import Header from "./header";
import { useTheme } from "emotion-theming";

export default function Page() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleClick = () => {
    setText("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rendering page");
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <textarea
        onKeyPress={e => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            handleClick();
          }
        }}
        value={text}
        onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Digite aqui sua mensagem"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You will see that the `Page` component re-renders every time `text` changes. This is correct behavior. Usually, you should store local state as far down the component tree as possible, so only the smallest components re-render.

---

## Theme hook re-rendering

You `useTheme` hook was being called over and over again because you called `useTheme` in a component that re-renders (`App`). This is expected.

Now that all state has been removed from `App` your `useTheme` (now renamed to `useAppTheme` is only called once when the `App` component renders.

You shouldn't call `useAppTheme` in any child components. You get the theme from the `ThemeProvider` by calling Emotion's `useTheme` hook.

If you want to change the current theme, then the component that changes the theme can call your `useAppTheme` hook, but understand that every time that component re-renders, you `useAppTheme` hook will be called.

I've moved your button that sets the theme to your `Header` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "emotion-theming";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import useAppTheme from "./useAppTheme";

const NavBar = props => {
  return <div>ae</div>;
};

const Header = () => {
  const Theme = useTheme();
  const { theme, setTheme } = useAppTheme();
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <button
        css={css`
          background: red;
          width: 100px;
          height: 50px;
          border-radius: 10px;
        `}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("setting theme from", theme.type);
          setTheme(
            theme.type === "dark" ? { type: "light" } : { type: "dark" }
          );
        }}
      >
        a
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Regarding my Component header

as you can see
if I pass the:

<NavBar theme = {Theme} />

or even in my header component and I have a textarea it will render when I type
is that something that would have no problem?

Comment: const Theme = useTheme();
  const { theme, setTheme } = useAppTheme();                                                             const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const handleClick = () => {
    setText('');
  };                                                                                                                                              <Top theme={Theme} />

Comment: If you don't want your `useTheme` to rerender, then don't re-render any of its parent components, that includes `Header`, and `Page`. When the theme re-renders, it is not re-rendering your whole app.

Comment: A hook creates a new instance every time you use in in a component, for example, the `useTheme` hook in your `App` is NOT the same instance as the `useTheme` hook in your `Header`. It does connect to the same variable in local storage, but that's fine.

Comment: The reason your header is re-rendering is because your `Page` is re-rendering (when the state of `text` changes). If you want to prevent that, move the `text` state and the `textarea` input into a child component of `Page`.

Comment: And to answer your question, yes it's fine that `useTheme` renders multiple times. There's nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: but in my header I will have a search textfield

Comment: ahh so i won't worry, thank you very much, i saw something about useMemo and memo but i don't know if it would fit well in this case

Comment: Then the search text field should be inside a child component of the `Header`. To prevent the `Header` (and therefore the `useTheme`) from re-rendering, don't store state in your `Header` component. Create a child component called `SearchField` and store the search text state inside that. Then render the `SearchField` inside your header. The `Header` will not re-render.